# eclipse does not match constructor method call

Tags: java, eclipse, methods, constructor, keyboard-shortcuts

when pressing **ctrl+space** in eclipse I remember it used to match the objects for the data type in the **diamond operator**. but it dosn't anymore . for example :

`public static void main(String[] args) {

        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<**MISSING**>()
    }`

anyway to turn it back on?
thnx.

Comment: you need to import HashMap before getting that functionality

Comment: Which version of java are you using ?

Comment: Eclipse won't fill in the type when compiler is set to Java 7 compliance, because in Java 7 it's ok to omit the type parameter in this case. In Java 6, it isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe because you are using Java7 compiler, which does not require params in the diamond operator.

Read more about it here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/type-inference-generic-instance-creation.html

Answer (score 1):

Are you running Java 7 ?

It's a new feature they added called "[Type Inference for Generic Instance Creation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/type-inference-generic-instance-creation.html)"

> You can replace the type arguments required to invoke the constructor
>   of a generic class with an empty set of type parameters (<>) as long
>   as the compiler can infer the type arguments from the context. This
>   pair of angle brackets is informally called the diamond.

Before Java 7 :

```
Map<String, List<String>> myMap = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
```

Now you can do :

```
Map<String, List<String>> myMap = new HashMap<>();
```

Comment: you mean I don't have to explicitly put it in the diamond, and it will figure it out from context?

Comment: @Gal If your compiler is set to Java 7 yes.

Comment: it is 7 , Got It thnx!